# Do I need to add 'const' when using 'auto' in for-each loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

To avoid copying objects, it's generally better to do

`for(auto &x : container){...}`

than

`for(auto x : container){...}`

But in regular C++, a reference is non-const which would allow the container to be modified. Should we therefore do the following as a matter of course, just as we make methods `const` whenever they don't modify data?

`for(const auto &x : container){...}`

Comment: Yeah, I guess you should.

Comment: Seems logical, as long as you only need the information in each `x` and don't intend to modify it.

Comment: it depends on ur plan on the x got passed in the for loop.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you want to do within the body of the `for` statement.

- If you want read-only access to the elements you're iterating over, then use `auto const&`.
- If you want to modify the elements, then use `auto&&`. I prefer that to `auto&` because it handles cases where dereferencing the container's iterator produces an rvalue (`vector<bool>`).

There's also a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm) to allow

```
for(x : container) { ... }
```

which would be a less verbose form of

```
for(auto&& x : container) { ... }
```

Comment: Why not `auto&&` for brevity?

Comment: @Deduplicator Why not always drop `const` for brevity?

Comment: So what's the difference between `const auto&` and `auto const&`?

Comment: @John There's no difference, it's just a matter of preference